Is there a way to allow an application to authenticate with an API without user interaction?
This question is more conceptual than code-based. I have a REST API that requires authentication, and a React Native app that consumes the API. The React Native app authenticates users separately and receives consent to access typical scopes (openid, profile). This data is managed and stored by a third party auth provider (Auth0).
What I don't want is for these users to be able to authenticate directly with the API; rather I want to have a separate user account that I manage be used to access the API. I considered a machine-to-machine flow but I've learned it's not advised because the clientid-clientsecret pair cannot be securely stored on the device. So my next option is to use an authorization code w/ PKCE, but as far as I can tell that requires user interaction in order to work.
Is there a way to accomplish what I'm aiming for without compromising the security of my API?
